# I want to trigger/run a py file from another py file and move to my rest of code, I have tried all of bellow functions but no one is working

Tags: python, subprocess, runpy

```
import time
import subprocess
import os
import runpy

subprocess.run(['python', 'process_1.py'],)
# subprocess.call(['python', 'process_1.py'],)
# os.system('python process_1.py')
# runpy.run_path(path_name='process_1.py')

# exec(open("process_1.py").read())

# rest of my code
```

I have tried all of commented functions but no one is working

Comment: What do you mean by 'move to my rest of code'? Do you want to continue executing the current python file or do you want to execute another file from the current file?

Comment: The standard way of doing this would be to make your 'main' code into a function or class in a module and have your 'runner' `import` the module. See for example https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the, current, python executable and also the full path to the file you want to run, like so:

```py
import shutil # Add also this import

# Get Current files full path
project_root  = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Build full path to the proccess_1 file.
process_1_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'process_1.py')

# Get path to python executable
py_bin = shutil.which("python")

# Run the file and wait for it to finish.
# subprocess.run([py_bin, process_1_path ])

# Run the file in background and continue this script's execution
main_code_process = subprocess.Popen([py_bin, process_1_path ])
```

Comment: I have created two files 1 is runner.py (which will run the code) and main_code.py (which will have the main codebase).
I have used this code in runner.py, it runs the code of main_code.py within itself. This means, that if there are bundles of print functions in main_code.py and other piece of code then those prints will be printed when the runner.py runs.
My goal is just to run the main_code.py and move to the next file to run those, not stay connected to the file after running it.

Comment: I see. You can run the main_code in background without waiting for it to finish execution by using `subprocess.Popen`. Read the docs here for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen